# how to display HTML files on BitBucket?

Tags: bitbucket, jira, python-sphinx, confluence, pdoc

We currently use GitHub for our code repos, which include HTML files for documentation. On GitHub, the HTML files in the repo only display the HTML source, but I can publish it to GitHub Pages, where it displays as a regular web page for my users.

We have just begun the migration to BitBucket hosted within my organization. It looks like the BitBucket Pages plug-in is the equivalent to GitHub Pages, but we don't have that plug-in and I do not expect to get it. **Without that plug-in**, is there a way to display HTML files as a web page? We also have JIRA and Confluence, in case those help.

I currently document my Python code with pdoc (pdoc3) to create HTML documentation. I don't think this question is specific to Python or pdoc3, but I just thought I'd add that, in case it matters. (I like pdoc3, but if another tool solves my problem, I'll try it.)

In short, how do I display HTML in BitBucket without the Pages plug-in?

Comment: I doubt it - that really is kind of the point of the "Pages" service. OTOH, putting up an nginx to host your documentation shouldn't be all that hard. (Or just a Samba share, really)

Comment: In [BitBucket's relevant docs](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/publishing-a-website-on-bitbucket-cloud/), there's no indication this is a paid service. Have you followed the instructions carefully? The app OP is referring to is an app by an independent studio.

Comment: Thanks, @K3---rnc - Unfortunately, we're not using the BitBucket Cloud version referenced in these docs. I think what we're using the "self-hosting" (Enterprise) option.